# CakePHP edit multiple records at once

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a HABTM relationship between two tables: `items` and `locations`, using the table `items_locations` to join them.

`items_locations` also stores a bit more information. Here's the schema

```
items_locations(id, location_id, item_id, quantity)
```

I'm trying to build a page which shows all the items in one location and lets the user, through a datagrid style interface, edit multiple fields at once:

```
Location: Factory XYZ
 ___________________________
|___Item____|___Quantity___|
| Widget    |          3   |
| Sprocket  |          1   |
| Doohickey |         15   |
----------------------------
```

To help with this, I have a controller called `InventoryController` which has:

```
var $uses = array('Item', 'Location');  // should I add 'ItemsLocation' ?
```

How do I build a multidimensional form to edit this data?

---

Edit:

I'm trying to get my data to look like how Deceze described it below but I'm having problems again...

```
// inventory_controller.php
function edit($locationId) {

    $this->data = $this->Item->ItemsLocation->find(
        'all',
        array(
            "conditions" => array("location_id" => $locationId)
        )
    );
```

when I do that, `$this->data` comes out like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [ItemsLocation] => Array (
            [id] => 16
            [location_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 1
            [quantity] => 5
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [ItemsLocation] => Array (/* .. etc .. */)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're not going to edit data in the `Item` model, it probably makes most sense to work only on the join model. As such, your form to edit the quantity of each item would look like this:

```
echo $form->create('ItemsLocation');

// foreach Item at Location:

echo $form->input('ItemsLocation.0.id'); // automatically hidden
echo $form->input('ItemsLocation.0.quantity');
```

Increase the counter (`.0.`, `.1.`, ...) for each record. What you should be receiving in your controllers `$this->data` should look like this:

```
array(
    'ItemsLocation' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'quantity' => 42
        ),
        1 => array(
            ...
```

You can then simply save this like any other model record: `$this->Item->ItemsLocation->saveAll($this->data)`. Adding an Item to a Location is not much different, you just leave off the `id` and let the user select the `item_id`.

```
array(
    'location_id' => 42,  // prepopulated by hidden field
    'item_id' => 1        // user selected
    'quantity' => 242
)
```

If you want to edit the data of the Item model and save it with a corresponding ItemsLocation record at the same time, dive into the [Saving Related Model Data (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/85/Saving-Related-Model-Data-HABTM) chapter. Be careful of this:

> By default when saving a HasAndBelongsToMany relationship, Cake will delete all rows on the join table before saving new ones. For example if you have a Club that has 10 Children associated. You then update the Club with 2 children. The Club will only have 2 Children, not 12.

And:

> **[3.7.6.5 hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)](http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM)**
>
> **unique**: If true (default value) cake will first delete existing relationship records in the foreign keys table before inserting new ones, when updating a record. So existing associations need to be passed again when updating.

---

**Re: Comments/Edit**

I don't know off the top of my head if the FormHelper is intelligent enough to autofill `Model.0.field` fields from a `[0][Model][field]` structured array. *If not*, you could easily manipulate the results yourself:

```
foreach ($this->data as &$data) {
    $data = $data['ItemsLocation'];
}
$this->data = array('ItemsLocation' => $this->data);
```

That would give you the right structure, but it's not very nice admittedly. If anybody has a more Cakey way to do it, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: that makes a lot more sense now.. though I'm still hitting a brick wall. Mind taking a look at my edit to the original post?

Comment: Well, the format will be slightly different when you **find** data. What I'm talking about is the right format for **POSTing a form to the controller.** Try a `debug($this->data)` in the controller upon receiving the POST data.

Comment: but won't you need it in that format for the view to be able to do something with like: `$form->input('ItemsLocation.0.id')`

Comment: This may help a little. http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/saving-extra-fields-in-the-join-table-for-habtm-models/